# Drupal Validation Function Not Being Called

Tags: forms

So I have a content type I am trying to add a validation function to.

```
function ocomp_source_type_form_alter($form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'source_node_form') {
    array_unshift($form['#validate'], 'ocomp_source_type_form_validate');
  }
}
function ocomp_source_type_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
    drupal_set_message("Validate function entered");
}
```

It is the first validation function being run:

```
#validate (Array, 2 elements)
0 (String, 31 characters ) ocomp_source_type_form_validate | (Callback) ocomp_source_type_form_validate();
1 (String, 18 characters ) node_form_validate | (Callback) node_form_validate();
```

I've tried everything I could and I still can't figure out why this validation function isn't being called.

Comment: And I managed to solve it. function ocomp_source_type_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

Comment: Do you need a solution or managed to solved it?